# Disable session when site crawled by Googlebot

Tags: php, session, googlebot, google-search-appliance

My PHP 5.3 server is handling session with use_only_cookies dans without use_trans_id, and session files are saved in a dedicated directory.

When Googlebot or the Google Search appliance bot, or any other non-cookie-supported browser crawl the website, a different session file is created for every requested page. I'm afraid that this files will use a lot of space disk for nothing.

Is it possible to disable session file for certain user-agent, or for browser that do not use cookie? I do not want to replace the session by the trans_id feature because it may have SEO drawbacks.

Is there an Apache/PHP directive, or settings, or any other tricks to have the following behaviour:

- if the browser do not support cookie (by user-agent blacklist or other methods), then we use always the same session file OR we do not use a session file at all
- for any other browser, use the standard session file handler.

Answer (score 2):

Certainly you can examine the contents of `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` and check for known bots. If it's a bot, then simply don't call `session_start()` (although it also occurs that this might have unwanted effects if your logic depends on `$_SESSION` vars further down the code).

Comment: ...and I've never worried overmuch about session data filling up a server. PHP's pretty good at managing this behind the scenes.

Comment: that may be true of most sites. But when your site has several hundred thousand pages, Google bot may crawl 20k per day, creating 20k new session files per day. If you save your sessions for a week, you would get about 140k sessions from Google bot alone, plus more from the other bots. On the other hand, we only get a few hundred unique human users per day. So 99% of our session files are from bots!

Comment: I can see your point and it's very valid. Since answering this originally, though, it's occurred to me that page crawling is getting more and more sophisticated. The most recent example is Google's mobile usability analysis and that directly affects your search rankings on mobile. If Googlebot is denied a session and not having that session makes your page less usable/execute slower etc then that could be a very bad thing for your page rank.

Comment: @ButtleButkus Another possibility also occurs: you could detect what user agent is accessing the site and assign a short session lifetime to crawlers. (I'm assuming ini_set allows access to session lifetime). Then you have the best of both worlds - googlebot gets the proper version of your site but your server won't be clogged up with excessive session files.

Comment: I don't think you can have different session lifetimes in the same folder but it might be possible if you save the bot and regular sessions in different folders. Still, from what I understand, it would be pointless to do that, because web crawlers do not accept cookies anyway. If your site usability depends on cookies, then your site will not be usable for web crawlers at all! We want to prevent sessions for web crawlers precisely because they do not accept the cookies we send them and so they start a new session with every page visit (=thousands per day).

Comment: I see your point. Thinking of my own use case, the stuff I actually care about being indexed is entirely stateless - state is only required to enhance the user experience as people shop. This is probably true for most sites that depend on a good pagerank and if it *isn't* then it probably should be.

PS: Having read around about this, Googlebot not accepting cookies is true for now, but might be changing in the future as this experiment hints: http://www.tomanthony.co.uk/blog/googlebot-accepting-cookies/

Answer (score 2):

```
if(strstr(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']), "googlebot")){
    $sid = md5("mygooglebotsessionid");
    session_id($sid);
}
```

Add this before session_start();

Instead of disabling session for bots, You can set a unique SessionID for the bot. Everytime bot uses the same SessionID, So it doesn't waste your session storage.

PS: Not sure about SEO drawbacks.

Answer (score 1):

`if (strpos($_SERVER[‘HTTP_USER_AGENT’],"Googlebot") === false) {
session_start();
}`

But I'm not sure if it's worth it. Session GC is quite efficient, and if anybody will override user agent to googlebot, he will not have session

Comment: " if anybody will override user agent to googlebot" - well they can get stuffed